# how to set content offset for scrollview in Dynamically Created texfield?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

i have placed Dynamically created textfield in scrollview.I need to set contentOffset for the scrollview. In textfield shouldbegin Editing i have given the scrollview. It works fine if i traverse through Done button. But in betwwen if i tap any textfield that textfield goes up and and i cannot see the textfield. It shows the nextfield offset but cursor is in correct textfield. My code is

```
  -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

{

```
if(enteredHealthyHeart)
{
    for(int i=0;i<[healthyHeart_TxtFldAry count];i++)
    {
        if(textField == [healthyHeart_TxtFldAry objectAtIndex:i])
        {
            getHHTag=textField.tag;
            NSLog(@"getHHTag %i",getHHTag);
            UITextField *tempTxtFld=[healthyHeart_TxtFldAry objectAtIndex:getHHTag];

            if(i<([healthyHeart_TxtFldAry count]-1))
            {
                int j =tempTxtFld.frame.origin.y;

                healthyHeartScrollView.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0 , j);

                NSLog(@"j>>>>>%i",j);
            }
            if(i==([healthyHeart_TxtFldAry count]-1))
            {
                healthyHeartScrollView.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0 ,tempTxtFld.frame.origin.y);

            }

            [tempTxtFld resignFirstResponder];

            return YES;

        }
    }

}
```

}

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly add tag to each and every UITextField;

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //Take reference of all UITextField u added let say u have 3;
    UITextField *txt = (UItextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:99];
    UITextField *txt1 = (UItextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:199];
    UITextField *txt2 = (UItextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:299];

    if(textField == txt)
    {
       [txt1 resignFirstResponder];
       [txt2 resignFirstResponder];
       //required scroll view offset here
    }
    if(textField == txt1)
    {
       [txt resignFirstResponder];
       [txt2 resignFirstResponder];
       //required scroll view offset here
    }
    if(textField == txt2)
    {
       [txt resignFirstResponder];
       [txt1 resignFirstResponder];
       //required scroll view offset here
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I added the textfields in array. Since these textfields are dynamic.            UITextField *tempTxtFld=[healthyHeart_TxtFldAry objectAtIndex:getHHTag];How will add view with tag for these textfields in array

Comment: At the time of adding UITextField dyanamically add also [yourTextView setTag:99];

Answer (score 0):

`scrollview.contentOffset` is the point at which the content view is offset from the orgin scroll view. In you code

```
healthyHeartScrollView.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0 ,tempTxtFld.frame.origin.y);
```

The `tempTxtFld` is out of hte content view of `healthyHeartScrollView`. This makes the `tempTxtFld.frame.orgin.y` be negative relative to the contentview of `healthyHeartScrollView`.
So you can't see it.

ps. I really do not know what you want to do.-_-

Comment: if scroll the view and if i tap any textfield i cannot see the textfield. tat textfield y position is 125 but the offset it is taking as 325. but i have given the y position for offset as  tempTxtFld.frame.origin.y. I want the textfield should be visible.

Comment: is the textfield subview of scrollview? if yes you can try this: textfield.frame.origin.y = -scrollview.contentOffset.y;